# Html.DropDownListFor() not showing selected value

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I must be doing something wrong, searched google and this form, but I can not find it.

I have the following class 'product', generated with EF, representing a database table 'product':

```cs
public partial class product
    {
        public product()
        {
            this.category = new HashSet<category>();
        }

        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public decimal price { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<category> category { get; set; }
    }
```

I have another class 'category', also generated with EF, representing a database table 'category':

```cs
public partial class category
    {
        public category()
        {
            this.product = new HashSet<product>();
        }

        public string name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<product> product { get; set; }
    }
```

The two tables in the database have a many to many relation realized by a linked table called product2category which contains a combined PK of category_name and product_name. category_name is a foreign key to [categroy.name]. product_name is a foreign key to [product.name] (category.name is the PK in the category table. product.name is the PK in the product table) I use database first and there is no EF generated class named product2category.

I have an action method:

```cs
public ActionResult Edit(string id = null)
        {
            product product = db.product.Find(id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> categoryList = db.category
                .ToList()
                .Select(o => new SelectListItem() { 
                    Value = o.name, 
                    Text = o.name, 
                    Selected = product.category.FirstOrDefault().name == o.name 
                }
            );
            ViewBag.categoryList = categoryList;
            return View(product);
        }
```

I inserted a breakpoint and investigated the value of categoryList property. It has 3 results (when expanding the Results View):

false, "Football", "Football"

false, "Baseball", "Baseball"

true, "Tennis", "Tennis"

I have the following view (omitted some HTML for brevity)

```cs
<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.category)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.category, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.categoryList)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.category)
        </div>
```

The view generates the html dropdown list but does not select the "Tennis" value. Or to say, it does not set the selected="selected" attribute at the Tennis option tag(To be sure, I also inserted a breakpoint in the view, to investigate the ViewBag.categoryList property but it gives the same result as in the controller):

```
<div class="editor-label">
  <label for="category">category</label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
  <select id="category" name="category">
    <option value="Baseball">Baseball</option>
    <option value="Football">Football</option>
    <option value="Tennis">Tennis</option>
  </select>
  <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="category" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

**I cannot find why it doesn't default select the Tennis option.**

Second question:

I also cannot edit or create products because the value of the name and id attributes of the html select element. The value is set to "category" but has to be something like category.name is my believe.

Comment: did u try closing in parenthesis  `Selected = (product.category.FirstOrDefault().name == o.name)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using SelectListItem wrong
Selected is a boolean value telling that item it is selected.
DropDownListFor should get the selected value in the html, which you are already doing

```
    // Model.Category is giving it the current selected value
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.category, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.categoryList)

    public ActionResult Edit(string id = null)
    {
        product product = db.product.Find(id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> categoryList = db.category
            .ToList()
            .Select(o => new SelectListItem() { 
                Value = o.name, 
                Text = o.name //,  REMOVE THE SELECTED LINE
                //Selected = product.category.FirstOrDefault().name == o.name 
            }
        );
        ViewBag.categoryList = categoryList;
        return View(product);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but the `code` Selected = product.category.FirstOrDefault().name == o.name `code` just gives the Selected property a boolean value of false or true. Anyone else with suggestions?